# How we deactivate home of iphone button in ios App

Tags: ios

Is it is possible to App not go in background. Means can we deactivate iphone home button ?

Comment: Come on, there is only one button on iPhone and you want to deactivate it?

Comment: Are you just wanting to stop the app from running in the background so that it launches from fresh each time. Or are you wanting to somehow stop people quitting your app?

Comment: it's possible only in jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 1):

No, it only means your application will be killed (not stay in background) when user presses the home button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rephrase your question. By no means you can deactivate Home button. Even if possible, what you want the user to stay in your app for ever and he cant use the phone for anything else ??.

You can get call backs when the app goes into background using applicationWillEnterBackground method in AppDelegate though.